# TypeScript "this" issue with scope

Tags: typescript, scope, this

My code snippet:

```
class MyClass {
    name = "MyClass";

    // traditional method definition
    getName1(){
        return this.name;
    }

    // method defined as an arrow function
    getName2 = () => {
        return this.name;
    }

    // traditional method definition using a this parameter
    getName3(this: MyClass){
        return this.name;
    }
}

const c = new MyClass();
const obj = {
    name: "obj",
    getName1: c.getName1,
    getName2: c.getName2,
    getName3: c.getName3
};

const g = c.getName3;

console.log(c.getName1());
// "MyClass" because this is called in the context of c
// using a traditional method definition getName1

console.log(c.getName2());
// "MyClass" because this is called in the context of c
// using an arrow function getName2

console.log(c.getName3());
// "MyClass" because this is called in the context of c
// using a traditional method definition getName3, having
// a this parameter that statically enforce the context of c

console.log(obj.getName1()); 
// "obj" because this is called in the context of obj
// using the MyClass traditional method definition getName1()
// and assigning it to obj's getName1 property

console.log(obj.getName2()); 
// "MyClass" because this is called in the context of obj
// using an arrow function getName2 and assigning it 
// to obj's getName2 property, but which will preserve c's context
// nonetheless

console.log(obj.getName3()); 
// "obj" but why? Isn't the context of this enforced as that of MyClass? Shouldn't I get
// « The 'this' context of type 'obj' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'MyClass' »

console.log(g()); 
// Error, the 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'MyClass'.
// but isn't g declared in the global this context?
```

My questions are highlighted in the comments, but I will list them as follows nonetheless:

1. Why does `console.log(obj.getName3());` display `"obj"`? Isn't the context of `this` enforced as that of `MyClass`? Shouldn't I get something like:

> The 'this' context of type 'obj' is not assignable to method's 'this'
> of type 'MyClass'

2. I understand that `g` isn't declared in the context of an object/class, but isn't it declared in the global object context, and thus `this` should refer to `globalThis`? If so, then why do I get the following:

> The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this'
> of type 'MyClass'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think typescript infers the "outer" object as this and so you get "obj" from obj.getName3()  which is okay because it also matches the class. It has the name attr and all methods so its okay.

If you change obj.name into obj.noname (or one of the fn names) you can not call obj.getName3() because then the obj does not match the class anymore.

Same goes for g(). The outer object of g is void and has no name attribute (and the fns) so you get the other error message.

Read more: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#declaring-this-in-a-function